# Parsing Python string for data to create a class object

Tags: python, string, parsing

Although I've seen similar questions about this on here none have really explained in a way I think applies to me. I'm working on an RPG game in python and I store my character's inventory in a text file. However when I try to return these inventory items as an Item() class object I'm having issues. Each item is stored as: 'level 10 armor of water' or something along these lines. They are stored as the item's name which contains all the information needed for the object. --> Item(item_type, item_level, item_element, name). Is there anyway to extract this data needed from the object's name in string form?

```
#inventory.txt:
['', '', '', 'level 10 armor of water', '', '', '', '', '', '']

#Item() constuctor
class Item(object):
def __init__(self, item_type, item_level, item_element, name):
    self.item_type = item_type
    self.item_level = item_level
    self.item_element = item_element
    self.name = name
#Inventory Constructor
class Inventory(object):

item_slot1              = ""
item_slot2              = ""
item_slot3              = ""
item_slot4              = ""
item_slot5              = ""
item_slot6              = ""
item_slot7              = ""
item_slot8              = ""
item_slot9              = ""
item_slot10             = ""
slots                   = [item_slot1, item_slot2, item_slot3, item_slot4, item_slot5, item_slot6, item_slot7, item_slot8, item_slot9, item_slot10]
```

I realize this isn't the most efficient way of doing things but all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```python
with open("inventory.txt", "r") as f:
 arr = eval(f.read())

for item_string in arr:
 item = Item.from_string(item_string)
```

Writing `Item.from_string` is going to be a bit cumbersome though, since the name doesn't appear to lend itself well to parsing (e.g. "level 10 armor of water" instead of "level 10|armor|of water" or something easier like that).  I'd redesign your storage format, but if that isn't an option, you could use regular expressions, like so:

```python
class Item:
  @staticmethod
  def from_string(item_string):
    level_match = re.match("level (\d+)", item_string)
    item_level = level_match.group(1)

    type_match = re.match("(armor|sword|backpack|etc)", item_string)
    item_type = type_match.group(1)

    return Item(item_type, item_level)
```

Also, *you will be executing whatever code is contained in `inventory.txt`*.  But since the game is in Python, somebody could just edit the source code for the game itself.  Realistically it isn't a problem, imho, but keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing text in this way, instead of using a structured format like `json`, will lead to problems.

But, in the meantime, you can load the attributes from the `str` as long as it has a structured/predictable format.

For instance, if we assume that the first two words are the string *level* followed by the level number then you can use that pattern so long as it's true 100% of the time.

```py
class Item:
    def __init__(self, item_type, item_level, item_element, name):
        self.item_type = item_type
        self.item_level = item_level
        self.item_element = item_element
        self.name = name

    # A @classmethod is good for defining another type of constructor.
    # In this example, the @classmethod is what builds the class out of
    # the name str.
    @classmethod
    def load_from_name(cls, name_text):
        name_text = name_text.strip()  # remove all surrounding whitespace
        if not name_text:
            return None  # the text is empty

        words = name_text.split()  # split the text into word tokens
        if words[0] != "level":
            raise ValueError("Must start with 'level'")
        try:
            level = int(words[1])
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("Second word must be valid int")

        # Now we want all of the words before "of" to be the item_type
        # and all of the words after "of" to be the element.
        if "of" not in words:
            raise ValueError("Missing 'of'")
        item_type, element = " of ".split(" ".join(words[2:]))

        # Finally we assemble the instance and return it
        return cls(item_type, level, element, name_text)
```

Notice how many conditions we have to check for. There's definitely many checks and errors missing. Here's what a structured format looks like:

```py
class Item:
    def __init__(self, item_type, item_level, item_element, name):
        self.item_type = item_type
        self.item_level = item_level
        self.item_element = item_element
        self.name = name

    @classmethod
    def load_from_save_state(cls, state):
        return cls(state["type"], state["level"], state["element"], state["name"])
```

Now, the data can be loaded from a json/yaml/whatever structured format super easily.

```
import json

item_config_json = """
{
  "item_type": "water",
  "level": 10,
  "element": "armor",
  "name": "level 10 armor of water"
}
"""

# In a real scenario, this would probably get a path name,
# and the json would contain a list of many dict objects.
def load_item_from_json(json_text):
    state = json.loads(json_text)
    return Item.load_from_save_state(state)
```